# DateTime.Parse with the "+" symbol

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, iso8601

I have a piece of code which parses and validates user input:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(userInput,currentCulture);
```

Current culture is being set (to en-ca or fr-ca) and the user Input is always in ISO 8601 format "yyyy-MM-dd".

If the user enters 1900-01-01 the date is created as expected.  **If the input is "1900-01+01" the date time created is 1899-12-31 6:00:00 PM**  No exception is thrown, the DateTime.Parse happily converts this to the wrong date.

To make this work I am using `DateTime.ParseExact(userInput,"yyyy-MM-dd",currentCulture)`.

So my question is not how to make this work (I have that) but whats up with the +01 or any + value?  Am I missing something in ISO standard?

Comment: What do you expect to '1900-01+01' parse to?  Are you saying it's a valid date?

Comment: You can replace `+` with `-` before parsing date time.

Comment: It might be best if you do some client side and server side validation to verify that your date is in the format "yyyy-MM-dd" otherwise display an error.

Comment: No i'm not saying it's a valid date, quite the contrary.  It should not parse, but it is parsing to a date.

Comment: Ah in that case what you need is to validate your user input before putting it through any parsing algorithm.

Comment: This is part of the validation.  And also refactoring, the code as it was written uses a try-block to fail the validation rather using a TryParseExact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only `+` in ISO8601 is in time offset part, and it looks like it is parsed this way in this case. But as far as I know all 3 parts of date required to have valid value before time offset is allowed.

I'd recommend using `DateTime.ParseExact(userInput,"yyyy-MM-dd",...` (maybe even with `InvariantCulture`).

`DateTime.Parse` accepts huge variety of inputs and tries to make best guess on users intentions. This feels like a case when it simply guesses in confusing way.

Sample values (first local PDT, 2 other with explicit time offset):

```
DateTime.Parse("1900-02"   ).ToUniversalTime()    //  2/ 1/1900  8:00:00 AM 
DateTime.Parse("1900-02+00").ToUniversalTime()    //  2/ 1/1900 12:00:00 AM
DateTime.Parse("1900-02+03").ToUniversalTime()    //  1/31/1900  9:00:00 PM
```

Which seem that `Parse` essentially treats `"YYYY-MM+0x"` as `"YYYY-MM-01T00:00+0x"`.

Comment: Yes I am using currently using the ParseExact with a culture, and soon to be using the TryParseExact to remove the offending try-catch (honestly it's somebody elses code smell).  Good point about the best fit / guess.

Comment: It the + is indicating the time offset (my first thought too) shouldn't the date get larger?  It's going back 6 hours.

Comment: @Blah_Blah, offset is from UTC, I've put sample values in answer that hopefully clear out some confusion. I.e. your timezone offset is "+06", while mine is "-08" - so we would be getting very different results for `Parse("1900-02")`.

Comment: Yeah I was just getting there myself, lucky I hit refresh first.  Add ParseExact to the list of best practices ...